# C# Reflection: How to determine if ParameterInfo is a generic type defined on parent class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a method signature like this:

```
public class Class1<TItem>
{
    public void CopyTo(TItem[] items) { }
}
```

where `TItem` is declared on the parent class.

When I use Reflection to parse this method:

```
// not returning TItem as generic in signature    
string sig = method.FullName; // ClassLibrary1.Class1`1.CopyTo(TItem[])

if (method.ContainsGenericParameters) // true
{
           Type[] genericArgs = method.GetGenericArguments(); // returns empty
           foreach (Type genericArg in genericArgs)
           {
               loM.cGenericParameters += genericArg.Name + ",";
           }
 }
```

I need to figure out what the generic type signature is so I can look at the XML documentation (need to build the funky generic type lookup signature). I need to map the method signature to what's in the XML documentation which looks like this:

```
<member name="M:ClassLibrary1.Class1`1.CopyTo(`0[])">
```

I'm unable to reliably detect whether TItem[] is generic and figure out how to get the generic index (generically).

When I look at the parameter signature, the `ParameterType.IsGenericType` is false as is `.GenericParameterPosition`. `ParameterType.ContainsGenericParameters` is true, but nowhere does it give me the generic raw type signature (ie. `'0[]` that the signature requires and is usually seen in the .FullName property).

This all works if the Generic definition is on actual method (ie. `SomeMethod<TItem>(TItem[] blah)` at which point I can parse out the parameters as I need to. But when the generic parameter is defined on the type I can't figure out the right signature to reference the parent generic type by it's generic parameter position.

Comment: You can get the position of the generic type on the containing class using `method.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments()` if `method.GetGenericArguments()` is empty or does not contain the type sought. Does that help point you to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're looking at the generic arguments of the method instead of the method's parameters. You'll also have to differentiate between an array and a generic type.

```
if (method.ContainsGenericParameters)
{
    foreach (var parameter in method.GetParameters())
    {
        if (parameter.ParameterType.IsArray)
        {
            var elementType = parameter.ParameterType.GetElementType();

            var genericArgName = elementType.Name;
            var genericParameterPosition = elementType.GenericParameterPosition;
        }
        else if (parameter.ParameterType.IsGenericType)
        {
            foreach (var genericArg in parameter.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments())
            {
                var genericArgName = genericArg.Name;
                var genericParameterPosition = genericArg.GenericParameterPosition;

                // If you need to differentiate between a generic arg that is declared
                // in the method versus being declared in the class/interface/struct:
                if (genericArg.DeclaringMethod == null)
                {
                    // Declared in the class/interface/struct
                }
                else
                {
                    // Declared in the method
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Things get a little weird when you have something like `Class2<>.Foo<>` below - the `genericArg` variable will have a `GenericParameterPosition` of `0` for both iterations of the `foreach` loop. Check the `DeclaringMethod` property for a null value to determine what that position refers to: the method or the class/interface/struct.

```
public class Class2<TKey>
{
    public void Foo<TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TItem> items) { }
}
```

Comment: The problem turns out to be the generic type array from the parent type. Single types work as expected and return true for IsGenericParameter. For the array ContainsGenericParameters fires instead and you have to use the array check you mention. The logic for this gets pretty messy but it works. Thanks...

Comment: Ugh - another related problem is how to get ByRef and Value types. For example if you have KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>. Because KVP is value type it doesn't behave the same as an instance type and the code above fails on it. Likewise with any by Ref (ie. public sealed bool TryGetValue(TKey key, ref TValue value). Sigh - any ideas appreciated.